# convert a HttpResponseMessage to an object

Tags: http, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this structure, I am using **System.Net.Http** and **Newtonsoft** as well.
I need receive the webservice response and convert it in my class, but I don't know how to do that with a HttpResponseMessage and the posts that I've red hasn't helped me.
It's a Xamarin.forms project.

```
 public static async Task<User> PostLoginAsync(string login, string senha)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                login = "email@hotmail.com";
                senha = "1111111";

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", "1200"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", login),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", senha),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("json", "1"),
                     });

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://ws.site.com", content);

                return null;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

my class:

```
class User
{
    public string codigo { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string senha { get; set; }
    public string imagem { get; set; }
    public DateTime dataDeNasc { get; set;}
    public string cidade { get; set; }
    public string estado { get; set; }
    public string telefone { get; set; }
    public string sexo { get; set; }
}
```

If you can help me...I would appreciate that.
Thank you anyways

Answer (score 18):

You need to await the content from the HttpResponseMessage.

```
public static async Task<User> PostLoginAsync(string login, string senha)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            login = "email@hotmail.com";
            senha = "1111111";

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", "1200"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", login),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", senha),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("json", "1"),
                 });

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://ws.site.com", content);

            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(responseContent);

            return user;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0."
It's a newtonsoft error..I searched what caused this error and it seems that I am not receiving a json for deserialize and in fact it isn't a json, then this error appears...But I can be wrong about that, but makes sense

Comment: I am using: 
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("mysite", content);

                    var converting = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(converting);

Comment: @JoycedeLanna If you are not sure about the type of response you receive, hit a breakpoint before serializing and check the response or else check in Postman or similar way.

Comment: .-. but I thought it is a HttpResponseMessage....
.-.
and its my problem...I need a json to deserilize

Comment: @JoycedeLanna In order for you to receive JSON, the service has to pass JSON. There may be services which return data of some other formats like HTML, XML, etc. So better make sure you really get JSON from the service.

Comment: @JoycedeLanna I edited my answer to give a better context. It also fixes the second use of "content". I haven't taken care off. You can see what is coming in the response if you set a breakpoint at 'var user = Json...`.

Comment: Working for me using net core 6, thanks